# Using logic to check if a variable is set

Tags: python

Sounds simple. I'm making a "game" for a Python tutorial (Python the Hard Way, ex36).

If the player selects "ahead" while the variable theObject is not set, they are prompted to first obtain an object, then opening() is meant to run. Does not seem to work though.

Here is ahead()

```
# ahead
def ahead():
    if theObject not in globals():
        print "You need an object before you can proceed."
        opening()

    else:
        print "You walk for a while."
        print "Eventually you find a door to exit the Labrynthe with a code above it"
        print "You must translate the code using the code translator."
        print theObject
        if theObject == "map":
            print "You gotta get the code."
            dead("You walked too far to return. You die of exhaustion")
        elif theObject == "code":
            print "You say out aloud the magic open words 'open sesame!'"
            complete()
        else:
            print "Grab the code from the left room."
            opening()
```

I tested it out by calling ahead() from within the game, hoping to be given the message "You need an object before you can proceed" and then being presented with opening().

But I got this instead:

```
ex36.py:64: SyntaxWarning: name 'theObject' is assigned to before global declaration
  global theObject
ex36.py:73: SyntaxWarning: name 'theObject' is assigned to before global declaration
  global theObject
You're in a Labrynthe.
There's a door on your left.
There's a door on your right.
Or you can go ahead.
>
```

It appears that the message is not being printed and instead the Syntax warning is being delivered.

Why does my code not just say "You need an object before you can proceed" as expected?

Comment: Why not give it a sane default value instead?

Comment: Keys in `globals()` are *strings*, `'theObject' in globals()` would work. But why not just do what Ignacio proposes?

Comment: Your warning appears to be coming from an entirely different function. Also, you should really just initialize the variable to `False` and then set it to `True` once the player has the thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip user...112. I will try that except that theObject needs to be used by more than one function, so, to my knowledge, must be global. Will changing the true/false setting of the Object within a function set it outwith the function too?

Comment: @DougFirr: Please show us lines 64 and 73 (With context)

Comment: @DougFirr if you set it as a global, it will. This is not the best implementation of what you're trying to accomplish though.... It would be better to create an `player` class that has an `inventory` attribute that would contain whatever items your character has, then pass the player class to each function, and check `if "map" in player.inventory: #do stuff` etc.

Comment: @adsmith thanks for the info. That certainly sounds logical. My tutorial has not covered classes yet but sounds simple enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`globals()` returns a dictionary. Try:

```
# ahead
def ahead():
    if 'theObject' not in globals():
        print "You need an object before you can proceed."
        opening()

    else:
        print "You walk for a while."
        print "Eventually you find a door to exit the Labrynthe with a code above it"
        print "You must translate the code using the code translator."
        print theObject
        if theObject == "map":
            print "You gotta get the code."
            dead("You walked too far to return. You die of exhaustion")
        elif theObject == "code":
            print "You say out aloud the magic open words 'open sesame!'"
            complete()
        else:
            print "Grab the code from the left room."
            opening()
```

Now that I've answered your question, a word of caution. This is not really the best way to do this. One way to avoid this, is to set `theObject` to `None` in the beginning, and then, you know it is always available.

Taking a further step back, mutating variables in functions is really bad practice and leads to code that is a nightmare to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, accepting shortly. I'll try defining the variable as False as per comment above. But yeah, adding '' to the object name worked

Comment: "Taking a further step back, mutating variables in functions is really bad practice and leads to code that is a nightmare to debug." You have no idea how many hours I've spent debugging `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute <whatever>` because list.append is a mutator and doesn't return the appended list. BUILT-IN METHODS, WHY MUST YOU TORMENT ME?!

Comment: @adsmith: Mutating global variables in functions `!=` mutating the current object's state in methods

Comment: @Eric but the point stands that it's safer to return the value rather than making the change in-place. Yes, mutating globals is worse -- I don't think that point is up for discussion. This one of only a couple things Ruby has that I miss in Python (the '!' character implying an in-place method)

Comment: @adsmith: `l.append(x)` => `l + [x]`. Admittedly it's not easy to work out one from the other like it is in ruby

Comment: @Eric, not really, since `l + [x]` would return a new list after performing the operation. To better illustrate, I created a fiddle. http://pythonfiddle.com/

Comment: @Eric That's my point exactly, it's not easy to work out one from the other! But that's neither here nor there, nor pertinent to solving this question :)

Comment: Fiddle address was wrong, here is what I meant to link to: http://pythonfiddle.com/list-append-vs-addition

Comment: @zsquare: I wasn't implying they did the same thing, although that may not have been clear. One is the non-mutating form of the other.

Comment: @adsmith: although `l + [x]` has the obvious mutating form `l += [x]`

Answer (score 2):

Much better to *ensure* the variable exists and switch on its value:

```
theObject = None

def ahead():
    if theObject is None:
        print "You need an object before you can proceed."
        opening()

    else:
        print "You walk for a while."
        print "Eventually you find a door to exit the Labrynthe with a code above it"
        print "You must translate the code using the code translator."
        print theObject
        if theObject == "map":
            print "You gotta get the code."
            dead("You walked too far to return. You die of exhaustion")
        elif theObject == "code":
            print "You say out aloud the magic open words 'open sesame!'"
            complete()
        else:
            print "Grab the code from the left room."
            opening()
```

Comment: Thanks! New to coding. That sounds so obvious now!